# How do you update network by command line (wp-cli) after doing an plugin or theme upgrade by wp-cli for a mulisite

Tags: wordpress

I updated my plugins on my Word Press multi site by

```
$wp plugin update --all
```

I updated my themes on my Word Press multi site by

```
$wp theme update --all
```

How do I update the network now on my Word Press multi site after the updates of the plugins & themes?

Using the Admin interface to do this is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this command in wp-cli:

```
 wp-cli core update-db --network
```

Tested with Wordpress Multisite and wp-cli 1.10

Comment: I actually tried this, but this does not update the network after a plugin and theme upgrade. It only upgrades the network after a core upgrade has been done. If you try this command after an upgrade to just the plugins and themes, then you will find that you get a message saying that the database is at the current level. This current level refers to the level when a core update is done.

Comment: `wp site list --field=url | xargs -n1 -I {} sh -c 'wp core update-db --url={}'` worked better for us, because the upgrade is done contextually (instead of checking everything against the root site)